# Conditional Field issue in Python with CSV File

Tags: python, csv

This is my code thus far:

```
with open('in.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('out.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        try:
            floatRow= float(row[3].strip())
            if  floatRow > 180.0:
                row[3] = floatRow - 180.0
                writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                if floatRow < 180.0:
                    row[3] = floatRow + 180.0
                else:
                    writer.writerow(row)

        except ValueError,e:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The issue comes in the `if`/`else` statement. The 'if' statement works (as in the subtraction of 180), whereas the `else` statement will not work. The script runs fine, but it will eliminate all records with a value under 180 for some reason.

Where am I going wrong and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't write the row (`writer.writerow(row)` is missing) for that `if` block

```
if floatRow < 180.0:
    row[3] = floatRow + 180.0
    writer.writerow(row) # This is missing
else:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

---

***Note***: Since you are using if-else mainly to alter data for the row[3] column, I would suggest simplifying your script by moving the `writer.writerow` statements out and keeping only that altering logic within `if`-`elif` blocks

```
with open('in.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('out.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        try:
            floatRow= float(row[3].strip())
            if  floatRow > 180.0:
                row[3] = floatRow - 180.0
            elif floatRow < 180.0:
                row[3] = floatRow + 180.0
            writer.writerow(row)
        except ValueError,e:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: That hurts my pride that I did not notice that. second pair of eyes are sometimes needed. Thank you.

Comment: @WillB We all make silly mistakes. Anyway, also check the edit.

Comment: I originally had it as your edit, but I was trying all sorts of different ways to make the if/else work because I was dumbfounded as to why it wasn't working. Thanks again!

Comment: @WillB If your query was resolved, don't forget to accept this ;)